# How to change element at the page on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a **page with 2 columns**. 
Left column is a picture.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <br>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350X350" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..
</div>
```

I want to situate table behind the picture and I need to make it visible **only when someone places a mouse over a table's area**. 
At default I want to place image and to place table (see below) on hover:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <br>
    <table class="table">
        <caption>Basic Table Layout</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>City</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tanmay</td>
                <td>Bangalore</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sachin</td>
                <td>Mumbai</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</div>
```

So, on hover: http://www.bootply.com/FmxIhVK0Pq
by default: http://www.bootply.com/jS76schLTB

Comment: So you want the table to replace the image on hover?

Comment: Yes, exactly. When someone navigate to image it is invisible and table will appear instead of it.

Comment: It's going to get weird when the image's area is too small for the table. Things will be jumping around on your page.

Comment: It's small table. And I'll have image the same size at the main screen. I'm not sure it'll convert them in the same way for different resolutions.

Comment: Also consider how this will work on touch devices (potentially half your users, or more).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would `absolute` position the image and do `opacity: 0;` on hover [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/wsshgbsv/)

```
.the_image{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;left:0px;
}
.the_image:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Absolute position will allow the table to be underneath the image. So it wont show both.

```css
.the_image{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;left:0px;
}
.the_image:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="table"> <caption>Basic Table Layout</caption> <thead> <tr> <th>Name</th> <th>City</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr> <td>Tanmay</td> <td>Bangalore</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Sachin</td> <td>Mumbai</td>
</tr> </tbody> </table>

<img src="http://placehold.it/350X350" class="the_image">
```

---

Another solution would be to have the table `display:none;` by default, and when you hover the image, to change it to `display:block;` and also change the image back to `display:none;`

**Edit:** Removed code for the **SECOND** solution because it flickered the image, if the idea is possible then someone with more CSS knowledge than me could add the code :) *(see nepeo's comment below!)*

[**First solution works!**](http://jsfiddle.net/wsshgbsv/)

Comment: Could you provide a demo? I see the oddness I mentioned in the comment above. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/er811qbq/2/

Comment: yes give me a minute the code was more of a guidance than a solution :)

Comment: found a solution for the first example, instead of `display:none;` you change the opacity, changed the answer

Comment: forgot to @isherwood you :D

Comment: I think using display none would clash with on hover, because once it vanishes it swaps to false... hence the flashing

Comment: @nepeo seems to be the case, perhaps only with javascript?

Comment: @Alexandros nah i've seen a similar issue with vanilla before, its part of the CSS implementation. Best to stick with opacity or visibility properties like your first answer because the element still exists in a way. The alternative is have a toggle using the js onmousemove and a timeout for deselect... but CSS only is better.

Comment: @nepeo thanks, I learned something as well, appreciate the input :D

Comment: @Alexandros thats alright, here to help after all! :) Plus point for using opacity is that it's animatable as well. `-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;`

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks, Alexandros. You have completely cleared this task which was so difficult for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got it right. But if I did maybe the best way is to use css selectors. so for example , You give them both absolute position or something like that so that table is behind picture (z-index smaller than table). and use pseudoselector like img:hover { display: none;} or even better img:hover { opacity: 0;}, whit this one you can use css transitions, also add smaller z-index than image so user can select things in table